# Calling C DLL From ASP.NET Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dll, pinvoke

## EDITED QUESTION

Hi this is the total workflow of this project

we have a application which is written in cobol, wee can communicate to that application using only a `C DLL`, the method which we have to call in the `dll` is given below

```
[DllImport(@"C:\CCExpert\haz450cp.dll", EntryPoint = "HAZ450CP", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    unsafe public static extern void HAZ450CP(ref p45_control p45_controlx, out p45_clreturn p45_clreturnx, ref p45_clclaim p45_clclaimx);
```

what we did is we are invoking that `C dll` from a `C# DLL`, this `C# dll` working fine with console application, it means we can give the input to it and we are getting proper output also from console application.

But when i try to call the same `C#DLL` from the `ASP.NET WebService` its giving error 
[image: Error 1]

### After select the debug option i get another window like fallowing

[image]

Thanks

Comment: maybe the way you call your function is not the correct and crash it.

Comment: @Aristos i created a `C#dll` and that `dll` will call the `C DLL`, i am able to call the same `C#dll` from console application and getting proper response, but from calling the `C#Dll` from ASP.NET im getting error...

Comment: Its possible that also the console fail/throw exception, just you do not see it. I think that you need to add here some code, the dll, and the way you call it. Do you know in witch point your pool crash ?

Comment: its also possible that you try to use any user interface library attached to the dll, and work on console, but fail on web that have not user interface. Check your dll what you have connected with.

Comment: @Aristos hi i updated the question added some screen shots also

Comment: @Aristos i debugged the code also, both for console and web apps,in web app when the debugger try to call the c method its throwing an exception.

in console app the debugger is able to call that method and we are getting output

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7788/discussion-between-raghuveer-guthikonda-and-aristos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this might sound a little stupid, but can your asp.net user read contents from the directory where the DLL is located?

You can do this test by copying you DLL to the bin directory of your web application folder and changing the DLL path from C:\CCExpert\haz450cp.DLL to just haz450cp.DLL

Comment: yup, i gave full permissions to IIS User for that directory

Comment: Try changing the identity from your applicationpool to LocalSystem, as on this picture (http://i.stack.imgur.com/m9U05.png)

Comment: we cant do copy because the total cobol app is installed in the `C:\CCExpert\` folder